# How to write out to a file and make it return the file

Tags: c++, xcode, function, class, file-io

```
int fileReading(string signalFile){
    ofstream fileName;
    fileName.open(signalFile, ios::in | ios::binary);

    //does more stuff here

fileName.close();
return 0;
```

}

How would I create a new file and switch the return type of the function to a file?

Do I need to create a class for this?

Comment: By file you mean `std::ifstream`? Or `std::ofstream`?

Comment: And what do you want to do with that?

Comment: I want the function to return a file at the end instead of an integer. @LogicStuff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest and probably the most consistent thing to do is to have your function take an `fstream` as argument (by reference) and then return it,

```
fstream& fileReading(fstream& strm)
{
    // process it here
    return strm;
}
```

This way you are not mixing file names with streams, so your function does only one thing: process a stream. Once you defined your function, you can use it like

```
fstream fileName("test.txt", ios::in | ios::binary); // we open the stream
fileReading(fileName); // and process the stream, will close automatically at exit from scope
```

If you try to return a local `fstream` (i.e. from inside a function), the compiler won't be able to (unless you use C++11), since `fstream` is non-copyable. In C++11 the compiler will use move semantics and move your local `fstream` into the returned stream. So in principle this should work:

```
fstream fileReading(const string& signalFile)
{
    fstream fileName;
    fileName.open(signalFile, ios::in | ios::binary);

    //does more stuff here

    // fileName.close(); // do not close it here
    return fileName;
}
```

Then use as

```
fstream f = fileReading("test.txt");
```

However, the support for moveable streams seems to be broken in g++4.9 (works in g++5 and clang++). That's why the best is just to pass the stream by reference and return the reference.

Comment: what is strm? is that a stream?

Comment: @ForrestChanningHunter that's the name of your parameter, which is of type `fstream`